# How to use sqlx query_as with rust_decimal for money postgresql type

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to use rust_decimal with sqlx for money postgresql type and got error.

Of course i use decimal feature for sqlx.

There is [full example](https://github.com/barlog-m/rust-sqlx-decimal-example)

Table

```sql
create table inventory (
    id         bigserial not null,
    name       text      not null,
    price      money     not null,
    constraint inventory_pk primary key (id)
);
```

Structure

```rust
pub struct Item {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub price: Decimal,
}
```

Query

```rust
let si = sqlx::query_as!(
    Item,
    r#"
        insert into inventory(name, price)
        values ($1, $2)
        returning id, name, price
    "#,
    i.name,
    i.price
)
.fetch_one(pool)
.await?;
```

Error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:38:14
 |
 |       let si = sqlx::query_as!(
 |  ______________^
 | |         Item,
 | |         r#"
 | |             insert into inventory(name, price)
   |
 | |         i.price
 | |     )
 | |_____^ expected struct `Decimal`, found struct `PgMoney`
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is two problems. First I didn't read the documentation carefully.

> Reading MONEY value in text format is not supported and will cause an error.

But even after that, you need to use the conversion manually.

```
impl FromRow<'_, PgRow> for Item {
    fn from_row(row: &PgRow) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        let id: i64 = row.try_get("id")?;
        let name: String = row.try_get("name")?;
        let money: PgMoney = row.try_get("price")?;
        let locale_frac_digits = 2;
        let price = money.to_decimal(locale_frac_digits);
        Ok(Item { id, name, price })
    }
}

async fn add(pool: &PgPool, i: Item) -> AppResult<Item> {
    let row = sqlx::query(
        r#"
            insert into inventory(name, price)
            values ($1, $2)
            returning id, name, price
        "#
        )
        .bind(i.name)
        .bind(PgMoney::from_decimal(i.price, 2))
        .fetch_one(pool)
        .await?;

    let si = Item::from_row(&row)?;

    Ok(si)
}
```